# Sampling within an area and creating table Qgis

Tags: qgis

What I am wanting to do is import two point files, one harvest data, another soil sample results.

Once I have them I want to create a buffer area around the sample point (75ft) and determine the average yield, and standard deviation and then put all of the data into a table so I can run a principal component analysis.

I have been able to get the data into a spreadsheet by hand, but I am looking for a more automated way since I have several files (10+) I am looking at.

Comment: What's your actual issue? Importing the files?

Comment: My issue is trying to streamline the process, I can do it now but it is very manual.

Comment: You should use model builder to build a model, and use script to automate the process.